# How to get doc_values value for field?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I modify query below to get doc_values for fields?

elastic 2.3

`curl http://localhost:9200/_mapping`
returns
`{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "my_field": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: I asked before testing.  I do not expect that it is easy checking. Answered by myself

Answer (score 0):

`curl -X PUT "elasticsearch:9200/my_index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_index": {
      "properties": {
        "status_code": { 
          "type":       "string",
          "index":      "not_analyzed"
        },
        "session_id": { 
          "type":       "string",
          "index":      "not_analyzed",
          "doc_values": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

response
`curl "elasticsearch:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty"
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_index" : {
        "properties" : {
          "session_id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "doc_values" : false
          },
          "status_code" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

`doc_values` is true by default. It is not shown in this case. But `doc_values` == false is shown.

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/doc-values.html